# SPFx Extension - Application customizer - List all components on the page

Tags: modern-experience, spfx-extensions, applicationcustomizers

Is there a way to list/ iterate all OOTB components on the modern SharePoint online site page?

Under developer tools I can see an ID `'spoAppComponent'` but not able to access/ unmount the same `ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('spoAppComponent'))`

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the [React Developer Tools Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en). It displays all react components.

[image]

If you don't already have it installed, check it out. It might be quite useful for debugging modern SharePoint pages.